# how to make a proper schema for the arguments

Tags: idl, deserialization, anchor-program-idl, borsh, decode

there are arguments

```
      "args": [
        {
          "name": "decimals",
          "type": "u8"
        },
        {
          "name": "mintAuthority",
          "type": "publicKey"
        },
        {
          "name": "freezeAuthority",
          "type": {
            "defined": "COption<Pubkey>"
          }
        }
      ]
```

**How to make the correct schema to be used in borsh.js?**

**I tried something like this**

```
const schema = {
  struct: {
    decimals: "u8",
    mintAuthority: "string",
    freezeAuthority: "string",
  },
};

or

class MyArgs {
  decimals: u8;
  mintAuthority: PublicKey;
  freezeAuthority: COption<Pubkey> | null;

  constructor(decimals: u8, mintAuthority: PublicKey, freezeAuthority: COption<Pubkey> | null) {
    this.decimals = decimals;
    this.mintAuthority = mintAuthority;
    this.freezeAuthority = freezeAuthority;
  }
}

const MyArgsSchema = new Map([
  [
    MyArgs,
    {
      kind: 'struct',
      fields: [
        ['decimals', 'u8'],
        ['mintAuthority', 'publicKey'],
        ['freezeAuthority', { kind: 'option', type: 'publicKey' }],
      ],
    },
  ],
]);

const data = "bT1LdJiCtzLAHMaiFmacn9H5oEZbRNsD6un3YxFXLYX6aixPPcaebNgLjwnMxzsEQ7uHaVmG3f5MPax7VEPAbJXYY1Q";

const resultDecode = deserialize(
  MyArgsSchema, // MyArgsSchema or schema
  Buffer.from(bs58.decode(data)),
);
console.log(resultDecode); // Error Invalid schema....
```

**but it threw an error**

```
Error: Invalid schema: {} expected option, enum, array, set, map, struct or u8, u16, u32, u64, u128, i8, i16, i32, i64, i128, f32, f64, bool, string
```

How to correctly specify the type for `publicKey` and

```
"type": {
   "defined": "COption<Pubkey>"
 }
```

i`m use "borsh": "^2.0.0" version, "bs58": "^5.0.0",

Answer (score 2):

`Pubkey` is not part of the borsh specification. It can be represented as a `[u8; 32]` instead. Should look something like:

```
class MyArgs {
  decimals: u8;
  mintAuthority: PublicKey;
  freezeAuthority: Pubkey | null;

  constructor(decimals: u8, mintAuthority: Uint8Array, freezeAuthority: Uint8Array | null) {
    this.decimals = decimals;
    this.mintAuthority = new PublicKey(mintAuthority);
    this.freezeAuthority = freezeAuthority !== null ? new PublicKey(mintAuthority) : null ;
  }
}

const MyArgsSchema = new Map([
  [
    MyArgs,
    {
      kind: 'struct',
      fields: [
        ['decimals', 'u8'],
        ['mintAuthority', '[32]'],
        ['freezeAuthority', { kind: 'option', type: '[32]' }],
      ],
    },
  ],
]);
```